# What condition satisfies the equation.

Tags: trigonometry

$f(x) = x^2 - 2x + \sin^2 \alpha$ = 0, if

- $-1 \leq x \leq 1$
- $\phantom{-}0 \leq x \leq 2$
- $\phantom{-}0 \leq x \leq 4$
- $-2 \leq x \leq 2$

How do I solve it?

Comment: By completing the square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We complete the square, and express the equation as a difference of squares:

$$\begin{align} x^2 - 2x + \sin^2 \alpha = 0& \iff x^2 - 2x + 1 - 1 + \sin^2\alpha = 0\\ \\ &\iff(x-1)^2 - \underbrace{(1 - \sin^2 \alpha)}_{\large =\;\cos^2 \alpha} = 0 \\ \\ &\iff (x - 1)^2 - \cos^2 \alpha = 0\\ \\
& \iff \Big((x - 1) - \cos \alpha\Big)\Big((x - 1) + \cos \alpha\Big) = 0\end{align}$$

$$x = 1 + \cos \alpha$$
$$x = 1 - \cos \alpha$$

Where $$-1 \leq \cos \alpha \leq 1\quad \text{for all }\;\alpha \in \mathbb R$$

Comment: To post a complete solution: cui bono?

Answer (score 0):

If the question you posted is formulated correctly, you could reason as follows:
As $f(x)$ is just a function of $x$, $\sin^2(\alpha)$ can be interpretted as a constant. All you have to do is solve $x^2 -2x + c = 0$ for x, and check whether your solution fits the domain of x, taking into account that $0 \leq c \leq 1$.